# Relay not triggering on initiation

Tags: relay

*Issue:* I have a relay which is pushbutton controlled to turn it on or off.  There is also an LED connected to the MCU output pin controlling the relay. The whole thing is powered by an AC - DC power supply.

When I plug in the PSU and power up, the LED turns on but the relay doesn't turn on. After pressing button a few times it works and after that it works properly. After that this problem does not occur even if I turn on off the switch but it occurs when I put it in a different switch.

What can be the reason for this? I am using an optocoupler and a BJT based circuit for relay control.

Schematic of the relay circuit I am using.

I am using 510 ohms instead of 470 R.

[image: RelaySCH]

The relay works at 12V and the triggering voltage at PC817 is 5V via a GPIO pin.

An SMD red LED is also connected to the same pin as the relay output to depict the state of the relay.

Comment: To get an answer I think we need (a) The schematic of how the components are connected (b) The source code for the MCU (c) details of any measurements made in the debugging so far (d) links to the datasheets for the components. Please [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/695531/edit) the question to include the information.

Comment: W.r.t. ``but it occurs whenever i put it in different switch``, does the design allow for _switch bounce_?

Comment: Yes my code have switch de bounce and this error comes up very rarely.

Comment: What’s the purpose of the optocoupler in this circuit?

Comment: We need an accurate schematic including the LED. You can use the schematic editor to add it to your question.

Comment: Exactly how is the extra LED connected to the MCU output pin?  If you take that LED out of the circuit does it change or improve the operation of the relay?

Comment: @RahulGoyal - Hi, Note that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference (i.e. source name & link) for that image & remember to include references in future. (As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules differ from typical forums).

Comment: (As already commented, the schematic you copied into the question must be incorrect for your actual design, as it doesn't show the LED which you mentioned in the text. However, even if you are copying wrong information into the question (which is a separate problem) you must correctly reference anything that you copy / adapt & put into a post here.)

Answer (score 1):

If you calculated that base resistor right for that relay, then this cannot work because the maximum current of your optocoupler is 30mA, which is too low (not typical.)